# SFINAE: How it works with derived class?

Tags: c++, sfinae

I wrote the following code:

```
template <typename Type>
class Int {
public:
    int value;
};

template <typename Type>
class Class : public Int<Type> {};

int var;

template <typename Type>
void foo(Type newValue) {
    var = newValue;
}

template <typename ClassType>
void foo(Int<ClassType>& newValue) {
    var = newValue.value;
}

int main() {
    Class<int> c;
    foo(c);
}
```

I have compilation error because compiler tries to call the first implementation of `foo` (if I try to remove it, the code compiles correctly). Isn't compiler should use the second implementation because of SFINAE?

Comment: You're not doing any SFINAE here.

Comment: There's no substitution failure, so SFINAE is irrelevant.

Comment: You are talking about overload preference, not sfinae. You can use SFINAE to disable one of those overloads, but that would be a different question altogether - "How do I disable overload X to prevent compilation errors"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no SFINAE in use here. The first `foo` overload is chosen because it produces a better match then the other one (the match is exact, opposed to the other one). You can try going through [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) for more information on what SFINAE is, I'd also recommend watching [this awesome talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PFdWqa68LmA) to learn how to do it right (the talk is a bit more advanced).
What SFINAE means, is that when deducing types in a template you'd come up with ill-formed code, it doesn't matter as long as something is matched. In your case, both templates match, so normal resolution rules apply. With templates stripped down, your code comes down to:

```
struct Base { int value; }
struct Derived : public Base {};
int var;
void foo(Derived val) { var = val; }
void foo(const Base& val) { var = val.value; }

int main()
{
   Derived bar;
   bar.value = 3;
   foo(bar); // will try to call first foo and compilation will fail
}
```